# c#: Вынесение файла ресурсов в отдельный проект решения

Tags: c#, ресурсы

Есть решение, в нем несколько проектов. Например, проекты: осн. прилож., сервис прилож., библиотека1, библиотека2.

Во всех проектах есть одинаковые картинки, фразы и тому подобное. В итоге получается, что допустим картинка кнопочки "копировать" хранится во всех проектах.

Как вывести ресурсы в отдельный проект и использовать их во всех проектах?

В принципе можно сделать проект, положить туда файлик ресурсов и ссылаться на него,редактируя файлики *.Designer.cs.

Но как-то это не правильно. Опять же больно долго, менять свойство в коде, нежели в свойстве объекта button, Image -> выбор ресурса, нет там того общего ресурса. Как его туда?

VS2012

PS: добавить всем как ссылку во все проекты Resources.resx не работает:(

Answer (score 3):

В окне файла `Resources.resx`. Измените настройку **Access Modifier**: с `Internal` на `Public`. Добавив ссылку на *наш проект ресурсов* можно будет использовать ресурсы этого проекта.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Еще один вариан использовать ссылки на файлы ресурсов, как предлагается  [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10334095/3373603)